# APPS SCRIPT getvalues active e.range and setvalues to the other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 sheets the Mainsheet, Sheet2 and Sheet3 with the same headers but different ordered columns, Now, when after I edit the cell using onEdit(e) trigger from the MainSheet and column AU. It will copy the whole values in the row which in e.Range and paste the values to the Sheet2 or Sheet 3 to the next last available row but the values must be in the correct column. Sorry, I'm not good in explanation and English. Thank you

What I have tried, the code works but the problem is, it is not in the correct column.

```
function onEdit(e){
const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  
if(sh.getName() == "MainSheet" && e.range.columnStart == 47) {
let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
if(e.value.indexOf("N/A") > -1 || e.value.indexOf("1") > -1) {
let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
} else if(e.value.indexOf("2") > -1 || e.value.indexOf("3") > -1 || e.value.indexOf("4") > -1) {
let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 3");
dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}else{
Browser.msgBox("Please select from the list");
}
 }
```

Comment: Please specify from which column you want data transfer to be done: for example MasterSheet.ColumnA >> Sheet2.ColumnB

Comment: Hi, I'm not referencing in 1 or 2 or  3 columns only. My MainSheet have many columns I want the values to be pasted in the correct column Header name in finding the exact Headers Name from the MainSheet

Comment: So, you want script to take column header name from MainSheet and then find exact the same name in some other sheet?

Comment: Hi, Yes, finds the corresponding column in Sheet2 based on the header name in the MainSheet, and pastes the values into the next available row in the corresponding column in Sheet2. It is possible to do that in script?

Comment: You can take only the header values from Sheet2 and then search for an index in that array for the header value you took from MainSheet. When you get an index, you add 1 (because columns start from 1 and array indexes from 0) and you get in which column in Sheet2 you have to copy value from MainSheet. Find lastRow in that found column, add 1 for the first empty cell and set value in that cell to be copied value from MasterSheet.

Comment: Good idea, do you have a code for that? or to modify my code to make that happen

Comment: If you have 47 cells with a data, it could be an issue to trigger onEdit() function with searching right Sheet2 column by a header name and placing data in a certain cell. setValues(someArray) copies all data in one request, but in you case, making setValue(singleCellData) will have 46 requests. It would be better to do it with separate function, that makes variation between two arrays (input array from MasterSheet and output array for Sheet 2 or 3, and after that calls setValues. Here are some limits of onEdit trigger. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers